# wpf: Buttons, Textboxes, getting cut off

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am really confused why some of my textboxes and buttons are being cut off, could someone please help me fix this problem? Thanks!!

**XAML CODE**

```
<Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Name="tabHome">
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <Label Content="Home" MouseLeftButtonDown="tabHome_Click"/>
                </TabItem.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <Button Content="Parse" Height="23" x:Name="btn_parse" Width="75" Click="buttonParse_Click" Margin="180,10,180,176"/>
                    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True"  x:Name="txtbox_filepath" Height="25" Width="135" Margin="151,52,150,132" />
                    <Button Content="Reset" Height="23" x:Name="btn_reset" Width="75" Margin="180,122,180,64" Click="buttonReset_Click"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Name="tabConfig">
                <TabItem.Header>
                <Label Content="Configuration" MouseLeftButtonDown="tabConfig_Click"/>
                </TabItem.Header>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <StackPanel Name="panelConfig">
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </TabItem>
<Grid>
```

**Screenshot**

[image: screenshot]

As you can see the button and the textbox is cut off in the corners.

Thank you for the help I appreciate it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you give a Margin value like this `Margin="180,10,180,176"` then it means that the control has to be placed 180 dip from Left and 10 dip from Top, 180 from Right and 176 from bottom with reference to the parent control. Your controls were clipped because of the high Margin values.

[image]

Note: dip - device independent pixels.

It is better to create `RowDefinitions` for `Grid` and place controls in separate rows with  reasonable margin value as shown below.

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Name="tabHome">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <Label Content="Home"/>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Parse" Height="23" x:Name="btn_parse" Width="75" Margin="10" />
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True"  x:Name="txtbox_filepath" Height="25" Width="135" Margin="10" />
                <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Reset" Height="23" x:Name="btn_reset" Width="75" Margin="10"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Name="tabConfig">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <Label Content="Configuration"/>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <StackPanel Name="panelConfig">
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you, I took your suggestion, and now how would I make spacing inbetween my buttons and textboxes?

Comment: Give a reasonable Margin value like 5 or 10. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

You're explicitly setting a `Height` and `Width` for the buttons, but the values you are using are too small.

If you leave them off, the button should display correctly:

```
<Button Content="Parse" x:Name="btn_parse" Click="buttonParse_Click" Margin="180,10,180,176"/>
<Button Content="Reset" x:Name="btn_reset" Margin="180,122,180,64" Click="buttonReset_Click"/>
```

Note that you can do a better job of the layout if you design this yourself using a `Grid` or other container instead of using `Margin`, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `Height`, `Width` and `Margin` properties.

Don't use the Visual Studio designer to create WPF UIs.

Take a look at http://wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html

Comment: @ReedCopsey That's exactly what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You have used height, Width property along with Margin property. Remove height and width property and it will work fine. Ex.

`<Button Content="Parse" x:Name="btn_parse" Click="buttonParse_Click" Margin="180,10,180,176"/>`